# Relative layout with wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I want to customize `AlertDialog` to have a fixed header and a footer with scrollable `RecyclerView`. So I tried to do it with `RelativeLayout` but if there are many items in `RecyclerView` then the footer hides below `RecyclerView`. And I add fixed height to the `RecyclerView` then if there are fewer items then there is extra space between `RecyclerView` and footer.

**With RelativeLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center"
android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
           android:text="Add Additional Information"
           android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTitle"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="16dp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:background="@drawable/popupTitle"
           android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/additionalDataList"
           android:scrollbars="vertical"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drlBottomMenu"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/offWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/continueButton"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**With LinearLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedCorner">
  <TextView
        android:text="Add Additional Information"
        android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/popupTitle"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/additionalDataList"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
    />
     <Button
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me in designing this.
Desired output should be:[image]

**EDIT**
After using constraintlayout I am getting following result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> Activity code

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView additionalDataList;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);

        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        additionalDataList = dialog.findViewById(R.id.additionalDataList);
        additionalDataList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        additionalDataList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        addDataToList();

        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList);
        additionalDataList.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialog.show();
    }

    private void addDataToList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            arrayList.add("Item :" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

> layout.test

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Add Additional Information"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/additionalDataList"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/additionalDataList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/drlBottomMenu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/drlBottomMenu"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additionalInfoTitle" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drlBottomMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additionalDataList">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continueButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[output when list has few items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22p8F.png)

[output when list has more items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq7lZ.png)

Comment: If there are fewer items then too the popup takes up the almost entire screen. I want it to wrap as per the number of items.

Comment: @Arti check updated answer try using `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: it is a better solution for your query @Arti

Comment: Above doesn't work it takes the full screen with empty space in between.

Comment: @Arti i have tested the above and its working for me can u share your code for alert dialog

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MaterialDialog` or `AlertDialog`, and then create the layout with `constrainlayout` + `guidelines`. It's way more easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/additionalDataList"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_marginBottom="height of bottom header"<-------------add this line
/>
```

> or you can use constraintlayout and set height to 0dp so recylerview
>   can take up availabe space
>
> one more option is to use linear layout and set it to wrap content and
>   dynamically inflate views

Answer (score 0):

Try using Constraint inside constraint like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Add Additional Information"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/additionalDataList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additionalInfoTitle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continueButton"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/additionalDataList" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
            android:text="Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/continueButton" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```